# QDoubleValidator accepts multiple decimal points

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlineedit, qvalidator

I'm using a `QDoubleValidator` for my `QLineEdit`. The application locale (set in QtCreator) is `QLocale::German`.

Now when I enter a valid double (either using a dot or a comma as decimal separator) writing to the textedit as well as converting the string to a float works perfectly fine. But the validator also lets me write stuff with multiple decimal separators. Strings like `123.567,890` or `,,03.4...` get validated but can't get converted into a float.

Is there a way to tell `QDoubleValidator` to only validate **real** numbers and not just strings without alphabetical characters?

I basically want to have a validator, that only validates strings, that can get converted to floats
using either the default locale or the german locale.

Comment: Why don't you use a [`QDoubleSpinBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html) ? It will automatically use the system locale, and you can [hide the up/down buttons](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#buttonSymbols-prop) if you don't want to see them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not used the `QDoubleValidator` so far but I could achieve such behaviour by using a [`QRegExpValidator`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexpvalidator.html):

```
QRegExpValidator* rxv = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[+-]?\\d*[\\.,]?\\d+"), this);
lineedit->setValidator(rxv);
```

Comment: Does not work: When there already is text in the lineedit, I can type whatever I want. When the lineedit is empty, I can't type anything. :/

Comment: May you mean `\\d[\\.,]?` instead of `\\d\\[.,]?`?

Comment: You are right of course, thanks for the notice. I edit the answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want only convert your content into the float and you don't want locale specifications, you can use `QRegExpValidator` with next deep `regexp`.

```
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?")));
```

Comment: my solution: QRegExpValidator *validate = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[0-9]*([\\.,]?[0-9]{0,2})?"));